# Custom Post Method Trouble (Routing Error on Post vs. Show)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, activerecord, routes

Trying to build a rails app in which I have a many_to_many relation between users and courses.

After establishing the relationship between my models with a join table, aptly named courses_users, I am trying to establish some custom routing to **create a new POST method**.

My routes.rb file is as such:

```
devise_for :users

resources :courses do
    collection do
      get 'my_courses'
      post 'add_course'
    end
  end

root to: "courses#index"
```

but I still get

[image: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CoursesController#show]

or

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CoursesController#show

Here is my rake routes output as well:

[image]

**Any advice**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is mistake in **`nested routes`**.

```
devise_for :users

resources :users do
  resources :courses do
    collection do
      get 'my_courses'
      post 'add_course'
    end
   end 
  end

root to: "courses#index"
```